# Fetch data from Mysql into php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  rol varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE subjects (
  subject_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject text,
  PRIMARY KEY (subject_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


CREATE TABLE users_subjects (
  users_subjects_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id_fk int(11),
  subject_id_fk int(11),
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id_fk) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(subject_id_fk) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (users_subjects_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

And in my code, a registered user whose role is 'teacher' and has assigned the subjects 'X',
can see in a table all the registered students with their respective subjects.

However, I am trying to perform a SELECT where the users whose role is 'student' are shown and have the same 'X' subjects assigned to them as the registered teacher.

I'm trying to do it this way but it’s not working:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where rol ='student' and id in (select distinct u.id from users u,users_subjects us where u.username='".$_SESSION['username']."' and us.user_id_fk=u.id and e.subjects=us.subject_id_fk);";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Can someone help me see what’s wrong with the SELECT? Thank you

Comment: may be you should look into joining tables . Looks like issue is here  select distinct u.id from users u,users_subjects us , these are 2 tables .. is it?

Comment: @zod yes they are, `users` is a table and `users_subjects` is another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the alias `e` but is not loaded. Also you test an equality between `subject` and `subject_id_fk`

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
where rol = 'student'
and id in (
    select distinct u.id 
    from users u, users_subjects us, subjects e
    where u.username='".$_SESSION['username']."'
    and us.user_id_fk=u.id 
    and e.subject_id=us.subject_id_fk
);
```

But this query will give you the user line related to $_SESSION['username'] if his rol is student. I guess the good query you are looking for is the following one :

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
JOIN users_subjects us ON (us.user_id_fk = u.id)
JOIN subjects s ON (s.subject_id = us.subject_id_fk)
WHERE u.username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'
AND u.rol = 'student'
```

Comment: Thank you for your code Astrea, but is not showing the users in the table, not even the students with any subject

Comment: whats that 2 from users and subjects ??

Comment: oups, is a mistake :)

Comment: Sorry Astrea this is still not working :S It doesn't show any students in the table

Comment: @ana  did sql execute with out error?  did yu execute in sql editor and see  by passing  username

Comment: Also, have you any subjects and the related users_subjects for your username?

Comment: Yes @astrea, I have relation with all the tables and they all have data

Comment: @Zod it doesn't show any errors either, it just doesn't show any students at all

Comment: I just created a new db in my local with your 3 tables, inserted some data and the query works fine. So, maybe there are other things that cause an issue. Have you an idea? Maybe other fields or where clause?

Answer (score 1):

/*Select a database and run these demo data for test*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `subjects`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subjects` (
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `subjects` (`subject_id`, `subject`) VALUES
(1, 'Health'),
(2, 'Mathematics'),
(3, 'Music'),
(4, 'Geography'),
(5, 'Science'),
(6, 'Social Studies'),
(7, 'Algebra'),
(8, 'English'),
(9, 'Physics'),
(10, 'Journalism'),
(11, 'Geometry'),
(12, 'Dance'),
(13, 'Dramatics');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `rol` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=97 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `rol`) VALUES
(1, 'Zacharys', 'teacher'),
(2, 'Xanders', 'teacher'),
(3, 'Brendans', 'teacher'),
(4, 'Jermaines', 'teacher'),
(5, 'Danes', 'teacher'),
(6, 'Sonias', 'teacher'),
(7, 'Maliks', 'teacher'),
(8, 'Willas', 'teacher'),
(9, 'Jeromes', 'teacher'),
(10, 'Simons', 'teacher'),
(11, 'Ferriss', 'teacher'),
(12, 'Hoyts', 'teacher'),
(13, 'Jacobs', 'teacher'),
(14, 'Chaneys', 'teacher'),
(15, 'Megans', 'teacher'),
(16, 'Jamals', 'teacher'),
(17, 'Basias', 'student'),
(18, 'Briannas', 'student'),
(19, 'Logans', 'student'),
(20, 'Hardings', 'student'),
(21, 'Hasads', 'student'),
(22, 'Shelbys', 'student'),
(23, 'Lucians', 'student'),
(24, 'Alexanders', 'student'),
(25, 'Ayannas', 'student'),
(26, 'Yuris', 'student'),
(27, 'Carissas', 'student'),
(28, 'Tallulahs', 'student'),
(29, 'Dantes', 'student'),
(30, 'Alvins', 'student'),
(31, 'Salvadors', 'student'),
(32, 'Camerons', 'student'),
(33, 'Lances', 'student'),
(34, 'Cleos', 'student'),
(35, 'Abigails', 'student'),
(36, 'Colorados', 'student'),
(37, 'Leilanis', 'student'),
(38, 'Hops', 'student'),
(39, 'Zephrs', 'student'),
(40, 'Ivorys', 'student'),
(41, 'Tylers', 'student'),
(42, 'Jaspers', 'student'),
(43, 'Jelanis', 'student'),
(44, 'Clintons', 'student'),
(45, 'Marnys', 'student'),
(46, 'Jeromes', 'student'),
(47, 'Madisons', 'student'),
(48, 'Kaseems', 'student'),
(49, 'Jennifers', 'student'),
(50, 'McKenzies', 'student'),
(51, 'Dantes', 'student'),
(52, 'Chancellors', 'student'),
(53, 'Adeles', 'student'),
(54, 'Leroys', 'student'),
(55, 'Salvadors', 'student'),
(56, 'Marvins', 'student'),
(57, 'Lucians', 'student'),
(58, 'Ignatiuss', 'student'),
(59, 'Chantales', 'student'),
(60, 'Britanneys', 'student'),
(61, 'Leandras', 'student'),
(62, 'Odysseuss', 'student'),
(63, 'Lens', 'student'),
(64, 'Ivorys', 'student'),
(65, 'Hollys', 'student'),
(66, 'Drakes', 'student'),
(67, 'Clarks', 'student'),
(68, 'Dieters', 'student'),
(69, 'Kirstens', 'student'),
(70, 'Lesters', 'student'),
(71, 'Beverlys', 'student'),
(72, 'Tads', 'student'),
(73, 'Destinys', 'student'),
(74, 'Alisas', 'student'),
(75, 'Salvadors', 'student'),
(76, 'Hunters', 'student'),
(77, 'Julians', 'student'),
(78, 'Lucys', 'student'),
(79, 'Francescas', 'student'),
(80, 'Ayannas', 'student'),
(81, 'Macons', 'student'),
(82, 'Solomons', 'student'),
(83, 'Jeanettes', 'student'),
(84, 'Audras', 'student'),
(85, 'Victors', 'student'),
(86, 'Vernons', 'student'),
(87, 'Marvins', 'student'),
(88, 'Zenas', 'student'),
(89, 'Xanders', 'student'),
(90, 'Gareths', 'student'),
(91, 'Henrys', 'student'),
(92, 'Eagans', 'student'),
(93, 'Alexiss', 'student'),
(94, 'Jelanis', 'student'),
(95, 'Brennas', 'student'),
(96, 'Ivans', 'student');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users_subjects`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_subjects` (
  `users_subjects_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject_id_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`users_subjects_id`),
  KEY `user_id_fk` (`user_id_fk`),
  KEY `subject_id_fk` (`subject_id_fk`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=201 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users_subjects` (`users_subjects_id`, `user_id_fk`, `subject_id_fk`) VALUES
(1, 48, 12),
(2, 19, 5),
(3, 5, 8),
(4, 69, 4),
(5, 73, 12),
(6, 85, 11),
(7, 33, 8),
(8, 20, 3),
(9, 2, 7),
(10, 30, 6),
(11, 21, 9),
(12, 50, 13),
(13, 14, 12),
(14, 79, 3),
(15, 36, 9),
(17, 72, 10),
(18, 89, 7),
(19, 94, 8),
(20, 56, 6),
(21, 16, 13),
(22, 4, 6),
(23, 29, 2),
(24, 20, 5),
(25, 76, 4),
(26, 53, 8),
(27, 48, 11),
(28, 10, 13),
(29, 13, 13),
(30, 84, 4),
(31, 12, 6),
(32, 46, 4),
(33, 20, 7),
(34, 19, 3),
(35, 62, 11),
(36, 84, 10),
(37, 62, 4),
(38, 94, 7),
(39, 29, 8),
(40, 73, 6),
(41, 75, 12),
(42, 50, 3),
(43, 47, 6),
(44, 73, 2),
(45, 52, 3),
(46, 28, 6),
(47, 81, 2),
(48, 96, 5),
(49, 23, 4),
(50, 57, 10),
(51, 2, 5),
(52, 36, 4),
(53, 29, 13),
(54, 88, 4),
(55, 43, 11),
(56, 69, 1),
(57, 16, 1),
(58, 18, 13),
(59, 20, 2),
(60, 25, 13),
(61, 75, 8),
(62, 32, 3),
(63, 34, 6),
(64, 47, 9),
(66, 15, 1),
(67, 53, 10),
(68, 39, 8),
(69, 91, 5),
(70, 82, 5),
(71, 65, 11),
(72, 86, 2),
(73, 61, 1),
(74, 34, 2),
(75, 64, 8),
(76, 65, 6),
(77, 10, 8),
(78, 78, 6),
(79, 33, 11),
(80, 69, 5),
(81, 51, 1),
(82, 56, 13),
(83, 6, 7),
(84, 77, 12),
(85, 23, 5),
(86, 53, 7),
(87, 71, 8),
(88, 3, 4),
(90, 6, 13),
(91, 54, 10),
(92, 1, 7),
(93, 13, 4),
(94, 55, 9),
(95, 88, 8),
(96, 22, 12),
(97, 19, 1),
(98, 93, 7),
(100, 95, 13),
(101, 8, 4),
(102, 13, 12),
(103, 41, 2),
(104, 6, 6),
(105, 54, 7),
(106, 5, 11),
(107, 58, 11),
(108, 1, 5),
(109, 20, 10),
(110, 66, 3),
(111, 28, 9),
(112, 21, 2),
(113, 91, 2),
(114, 74, 6),
(115, 50, 7),
(116, 70, 4),
(117, 47, 8),
(118, 48, 2),
(119, 20, 4),
(120, 32, 6),
(122, 25, 2),
(123, 42, 7),
(124, 89, 6),
(125, 94, 3),
(126, 27, 2),
(127, 90, 8),
(128, 95, 3),
(129, 86, 9),
(130, 65, 1),
(131, 14, 4),
(132, 61, 6),
(133, 33, 13),
(134, 43, 4),
(135, 17, 7),
(136, 69, 10),
(137, 29, 5),
(138, 43, 12),
(139, 90, 9),
(141, 88, 3),
(142, 45, 8),
(143, 52, 8),
(144, 56, 8),
(145, 72, 2),
(146, 15, 2),
(147, 25, 9),
(148, 91, 4),
(149, 16, 12),
(151, 62, 10),
(152, 64, 10),
(153, 17, 8),
(154, 55, 4),
(155, 19, 4),
(157, 14, 2),
(158, 7, 9),
(159, 90, 1),
(160, 45, 11),
(161, 55, 12),
(162, 35, 2),
(163, 1, 8),
(164, 41, 3),
(166, 28, 5),
(167, 43, 10),
(168, 91, 7),
(169, 77, 11),
(170, 38, 13),
(171, 3, 9),
(172, 72, 5),
(174, 80, 5),
(175, 46, 7),
(176, 87, 4),
(177, 76, 11),
(178, 1, 9),
(179, 34, 5),
(180, 46, 10),
(181, 86, 13),
(182, 53, 4),
(183, 48, 8),
(184, 5, 3),
(185, 58, 3),
(186, 6, 2),
(188, 81, 9),
(189, 75, 6),
(190, 40, 6),
(191, 52, 4),
(192, 65, 7),
(193, 52, 11),
(194, 59, 3),
(195, 10, 3),
(196, 64, 6),
(197, 33, 3),
(198, 3, 1),
(199, 96, 3),
(200, 66, 8);

/*
**Here is My Query Where If Teacher id is '5'
and we have to find out the list of students.
Where rol has two values 'student' or 'teacher'
As we need only students so have added !=**

Hope it will help you...

**SELECT U.username, U.id, USM.subject_id_fk, S.subject
    FROM users_subjects USM
    LEFT JOIN users U ON USM.user_id_fk = U.id
    LEFT JOIN subjects S ON USM.subject_id_fk = S.subject_id
    WHERE USM.subject_id_fk IN (SELECT US.subject_id_fk FROM users_subjects US WHERE US.user_id_fk = '5')
    AND U.rol != 'teacher'**

*/

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Brain! At the end this the query that works: `$sql = "SELECT *
FROM users uProf
    JOIN users_subjects usProf ON (usProf.user_id_fk = uProf.id)
    JOIN users_subjects usAlu ON (usProf.subject_id_fk = usAlu.subject_id_fk)
    JOIN users uAlu ON (usAlu.user_id_fk = uAlu.id)
WHERE uProf.username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'
    AND uAlu.rol = 'student';";`